# Search is obsolete?

Tags: lucene.net

```
Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
```

> Warning   1   'Lucene.Net.Search.Hits' is obsolete: 'see
>   Searcher.Search(Query, int), Searcher.Search(Query, Filter, int) and
>   Searcher.Search(Query, Filter, int,
>   Sort)'    \Archives.cs    65

So how will I search? with TopDocs?

if so then

```
TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(query, 10);
```

How will I know how many nodes it has found? And how to get a single?

Comment: TopDocs has `TotalHits` field.

Comment: good but how to get a single from TopDocs?

Comment: with hits it was hits.Doc(i);

Comment: `indexReader.Document(topDocs.ScoreDocs[i])`

Comment: can't get it. doesn't indexReader select by id?

Comment: maybe Document doc = red.Document( hits.ScoreDocs.ElementAt(i).Doc );  // ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, or  `indexReader.Document(td.ScoreDocs[i].Doc);`

Comment: How to remove an document? >_< I really can't find normal doc :)

Comment: `indexWriter.DeleteDocuments` or `indexReader.DeleteDocument(s)`

Comment: @L.B good :) I hope you can be a person who can answer all my Lucene.NET questions here. Now to not keep the question opened it's better for you to write something as answer so I can close it by accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-  `Hits` is deprecated since it silently makes background searches in every 100 results read , to be able to make document caching. Therefore it is inefficient in speed.

2- TopDocs has `TotalHits` field

3- `indexReader.Document(td.ScoreDocs[i].Doc)`

Comment: I've got another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083367/is-it-possible-to-use-something-table-alike-in-apache-lucene-net-nosql